# OpenGL. What should take glEnable for make texute transparent and with hard pixel edges

Tags: opengl, 3d

#### Given:

I have `x.png` image which contains 4 pixels(let it be square) with collors: red, green, blue and 4-th is transparent.
[image]

#### Required:

I need to find combination of arguments [glEnable()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml) and/or [glBlendFunc()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml)  which will give following effect: 
1) Texture applies without "smoothing", just sharp pixel edges. 
2) Transtarent pixel is transparent.

#### Current code base:

```
def set_3d(self):
    ...
    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    glTranslatef(x, y, z)  # for getting scale image
   ...
   # + here is adding background rect(blue) and rect with 4 pixels

def add_alpha_rect(self, batch):
    ... # getting textures, etc.
    batch.add(
            4, GL_QUADS,
            texture_group,
            ('v3f', (x, y, z,
                     x_, y, z,
                     x_, y_, z
                     x, y_, z)),
            ('t3f', (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)))
```

#### Current result:

[image]

#### Expected result:

[image]

#### Question:

How I can achive that result?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the texture magnification function. This filter is used when the texture is magnified.
The magnification function can be set by [`glTexParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml). Possible values are `GL_LINEAR` and `GL_NEAREST`. The initial value is `GL_LINEAR`.

Apply the magnification parameter `GL_NEAREST` to the bound texture object, to solve your issue:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
```

Note while the parameter `GL_LINEAR` would cause that the weighted average of the 4 texture elements that are closest to the specified texture coordinates are returned, `GL_NEAREST` causes that the value of the texture element that is nearest is returned, when the texture is looked up.

Comment: I've put `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST) ` right after `glBlendFunc` and nothing was changed. Maybe I call `glTexParameteri` in wrong place?

Comment: @YuriyLeonov You have to do it after `glBindTexture`.

Comment: @YuriyLeonov You're welcome. Note, if the texture is minified, then there is a minifying function `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`.